# How do I fix the error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm making a program to spam the bee movie script line by line.

```
import pyautogui
f = open('beemovie.txt', 'r')
for word in f:
    pyautogui.typewrite(word)
    pyautogui.press("enter")
```

and get the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'beemovie.txt'
```

I've checked if I spelt it right but it nothing seems to be working. I know this my have been asked millions of times but I can't find anything to help me.
I've already made a text file with the whole bee movie script.

I'm using Pycharm if that helps.

Comment: Where is the file `beemovie.txt` located? Is it in the same directory as your script?

Comment: it in the same file as my script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that your file 'beemovie.txt' is located in a directory other that the working directory of your PyCharm debugger.
One of the things you can try is to set the Working Directory (under PyCharm Configurations [Run->EditConfigurations]) to the directory where your file is.

Answer (score 0):

Your file beemovie.txt must be inside the same package (project package) or you need to set the path where the file is located.

Answer (score 0):

For me even though the beemovie.txt and Spam.py file were in the same directory, I had to include the folder name because the starting directory of my project was a folder higher than the folder containing both files.

f = open('Spambot/beemovie.txt', 'r')

### this is what ended up working for me. My file structure is Python Stuff > SpamBot > beemovie.txt/Spambot.py

there is no way a bee

should be able to fly.